# What is the idiomatic way to compose a URL or URI in Java?

Tags: java, url

How do I build a URL or a URI in Java? Is there an idiomatic way, or libraries that easily do this?

I need to allow starting from a request string, parse/change various URL parts (scheme, host, path, query string) and support adding and automatically encoding query parameters.

Comment: Upvoting the question long after it is closed because it is not clear whether a popular non-deprecated solution to this problem exists.  I found this by googling for 'java URL parameter class'.

Comment: My intent was to find a URL builder for Java, and this question is useful for me at least.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using HTTPClient worked well.

```
protected static String createUrl(List<NameValuePair> pairs) throws URIException{

  HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://example.org");
  method.setQueryString(pairs.toArray(new NameValuePair[]{}));

  return method.getURI().getEscapedURI();

}
```

Comment: This is now deprecated functionality. Does anyone know how to use the new HTTP Components package to do the same because it's stumped me.

Comment: The new 4x version does not support this any more.

Answer (score 80):

As of Apache HTTP Component HttpClient 4.1.3, from the official [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html):

```java
public class HttpClientTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "httpclient"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("btnG", "Google Search"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aq", "f"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oq", null));
    URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "www.google.com", -1, "/search",
                                 URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"), null);
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
    //http://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=
}
}
```

Edit: as of v4.2 `URIUtils.createURI()` has been deprecated in favor of `URIBuilder`:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("www.google.com")
        .setPath("/search")
        .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
        .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
        .setParameter("aq", "f")
        .setParameter("oq", "")
        .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

Comment: This works, but as of v4.2 URIUtils.createURI() has been deprecated in favor of URIBuilder. On the positive side this URIBuilder seems to have an addParameter() method so building request strings should at least be simpler now.

Comment: `URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("http")
            .setHost("www.google.com")
            .setParameters(qparams);` as @stian said

Comment: Println above prints the following; http://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=

Comment: tutorial link is broken

Comment: How to set path when multiple paths are to be given?  For eg.  "https://localhost/api/customer" + "/" +{Id1} + "/" + "summary?invoiceId=" + {Id2} + "&page=0&pageSize=10&q=" + {Id3};

Comment: HC v5 has the same functionality but the class is now part of the httpcomponents-core library

Answer (score 65):

As the author, I'm probably not the best person to judge if my URL/URI builder is *good*, but here it nevertheless is: https://github.com/mikaelhg/urlbuilder

I wanted the simplest possible complete solution with zero dependencies outside the JDK, so I had to roll my own.

Comment: It looks great Mikael, have you thought of publishing it to maven central? I know its small but makes using it easier. I can't find a similar class besides in JAX-RS. The lack of dependencies is definitely a plus.

Comment: It looks nice, but since it's a builder and thus mutable, why are there setters only for parameters, but not for host, port, protocol and path? And, well, no getters for those also.

UPD: Oh, it's not mutable - setParameter creates a clone. Well, still setHost/setPort/... could work same way. Or, perhaps, a mutable version would be nice to have too.

Comment: "simplest possible complete solution with zero dependencies" - Sounds like you know what is important! Your answer should be the accepted one imho. Including all of HttpClient (with all it's version updates and even deprecating the very API this question is about) just for building a url is what makes for top-heavy bug-riddled apps.

Comment: Finally on Maven Central, and it only took me four years to get done.

Comment: @mikaelhg Thank you! I need exactly in this moment!

Comment: I found this not suitable for my purposes as it creates a new instance whenever a parameter is changed. I want to be able to call builder.addParameter() in an if clause without having to set the variable to it. Is just ugly imho.

Answer (score 56):

[Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/index.html)?

Comment: As of Jun 2015: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e49

Answer (score 20):

There are plenty of libraries that can help you with URI building (don't reinvent the wheel). Here are three to get you started:

---

#### [Java EE 7](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar)

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
...
return UriBuilder.fromUri(url).queryParam(key, value).build();
```

---

#### [org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpclient%7C4.5.2%7Cjar)

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
...
return new URIBuilder(url).addParameter(key, value).build();
```

---

#### [org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.5.RELEASE](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-web%7C4.2.5.RELEASE%7Cjar)

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
...
return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).queryParam(key, value).build().toUri();
```

---

**See also:** [GIST > URI Builder Tests](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/b4f35bf5e5e5a444aff20c4616b51513)

Comment: EE 7 is the correct answer. All you have to do is pull in the entire suite of EE libraries, choose a JAX-RS implementation, resolve jax-rs version conflicts, and as a reward you'll have a handy UriBuilder class that works really well. Sarcasm aside, this *is* the correct answer.  :)

Comment: As of Spring 5 check out `UriBuilder` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilder.html) and  `UriBuilderFactory` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilderFactory.html)

Answer (score 15):

## Use OkHttp

It's **2022** and there is a very popular library named [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) which has been starred **41K** times on GitHub. With this library, you can build an url like below:

```
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;

URL url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .host("example.com")
    .port(4567)
    .addPathSegments("foldername/1234")
    .addQueryParameter("abc", "xyz")
    .build().url();
```

Comment: I fixed a typo, it's `addPathSegment` (not `addPathSegments`).

Comment: @PapaFreud both exist for different reason, reverted the fix.

Comment: If you're using OkHttp in your project anyway, then there is nothing wrong with this approach. However, if all you really need is a way to build URLs, I would doubt that pulling in a 770 kB JAR is the way to go.

Comment: @RobertStrauch I get your point. But it really depends. Not all applications are size sensitive. Pulling in a "big" jar won't make your application much slower. So the "disadvantage" is only the size and nothing else.

Comment: @TylerLiu I agree on that. The context for e.g. a mobile application is much different to some internal "enterprise" application. When in doubt, I personally favor the approach https://youmightnotneed.com is taking, though this affects the world of JavaScript. I first check which libraries the project is already using before pulling in further libs or write helpers on my own.

Answer (score 1):

After being lambasted for suggesting the URL class.  I will take the commenter's advice and suggest the [URI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) instead.  I suggest you look closely at the constructors for a URI as the class is very immutable once created.
I think this constructor allows you to set everything in the URI that you could need.

```
URI(String scheme, String userInfo, String host, int port, String path, String query, String fragment)
          Constructs a hierarchical URI from the given components.
```

Comment: But it doesn't provide functionality to actually construct and encode a query string from a set of name value pairs.

Comment: As the child prodigy said to Alan Partridge - one cannot have degradations of immutability, it either is or it isn't ;-)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lvFns5Lubc

Comment: URI's constructor does nasty things to the path. See http://blog.palominolabs.com/2013/10/03/creating-urls-correctly-and-safely/ for the details.

Comment: Let this answer stand as an example of how NOT to do this then.

Comment: String query... Thanks Sun/Oracle for the granularity. We will just replace all spaces with plus symbols, uri-encode all the parameters and link them all together with ampersand symbols ourselves then...  *bangs head on table repeatedly*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URIBuilder class included in Apache HTTPComponents Core5: import `org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5:5.2.1`, then:

```java
URI uri = new URIBuilder("http://yourapi.com/rest")
        .addParameter("count", "5")
        .addParameter("filter", "full text search")
        .build();
```

The httpcore5 has no dependencies but it's a 900kb jar file. If size matters, you can use this library instead: https://gitlab.com/mvysny/apache-uribuilder - I've only copied the URIBuilder out of httpcore5 and published the jar on Maven Central; the jar is 33kb.