# Java: String representation of just the host, scheme, possibly port from servlet request

Tags: java, servlets, request

I work with different servers and configurations.  What is the best java code approach for getting the scheme://host:[port if it is not port 80].

Here is some code I have used, but don't know if this is the best approach.
(this is pseudo code)

HttpServletRequest == request

```
String serverName = request.getServerName().toLowerCase();
String scheme = request.getScheme();
int port = request.getServerPort();

String val = scheme + "://" + serverName + ":" port;
```

Such that val returns:

```
http(s)://server.com/
```

or

```
http(s)://server.com:7770
```

Basically, I need everything but the query string and 'context'.

I was also consider using URL:

```
String absURL = request.getRequestURL();
URL url = new URL(absURL);

url.get????
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/is-there-a-good-url-builder-for-java looks to be a very similar question.

Comment: That is pretty generic question and I can't use the apache libs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
URL serverURL = new URL(request.getScheme(),      // http
                        request.getServerName(),  // host
                        request.getServerPort(),  // port
                        "");                      // file
```

**EDIT**

hiding default port on **http** and **https**:

```
int port = request.getServerPort();

if (request.getScheme().equals("http") && port == 80) {
    port = -1;
} else if (request.getScheme().equals("https") && port == 443) {
    port = -1;
}

URL serverURL = new URL(request.getScheme(), request.getServerName(), port, "");
```

Comment: If the port is port 80, will the URL string rep contain :80 text?

Answer (score 2):

```
URI u=new URI("http://www.google.com/");
String s=u.getScheme()+"://"+u.getHost()+":"+u.getPort();
```

As Cookie said, from java.net.URI ([docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)).

Comment: Sounds right.

I could use those functions with the servlet 'request' object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getServer(HttpServletRequest request) {
  int port = request.getServerPort();
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  result.append(request.getScheme())
        .append("://")
        .append(request.getServerName());

  if (port != 80) {
    result.append(':')
          .append(port);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [java.net.URI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the URL as it appeared in the request (e.g. leaving off the port if it wasn't explicitly given), you can use something like this. The regex matches HTTP and HTTPS URLs. Capture group 1 contains the server root from the scheme to the optional port. (That's the one you want.) Group 2 contains the host name only.

```
String regex = "(^http[s]?://([\\w\\-_]+(?:\\.[\\w\\-_]+)*)(?:\\:[\\d]+)?).*$";
Matcher urlMatcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(request.getRequestURL());
String serverRoot = urlMatcher.group(1);
```

Comment: I put minus just because saw here regexp

Comment: urlMatcher.find() should be performed before being able to retrieve the groups

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the StringBuilder, or concatenating parts of the URL, use the org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder class instead to form the URL. You could do something like

```
URL url = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(req).
                replacePath("/").build()
                .toUri().toURL();
```

Please find this [article](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder) explaining several ways to use this class effectively.