# Get the currently used protocol name from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm constructing a new URL in a Spring MVC controller, to be passed back to the client.   Currently I'm trying this:

```
// httpRequest is the current HttpServletRequest

new URL(httpRequest.getProtocol(),
    httpRequest.getServerName(),
    httpRequest.getServerPort(),
    httpRequest.getContextPath().concat("/foo/bar.html"));
```

Problem is that `httpRequest.getProtocol()` gives me "HTTP/1.1" instead of just "HTTP".    I can trim it but wondered if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598690/how-to-get-host-name-with-port-from-a-http-or-https-request & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104611/java-string-representation-of-just-the-host-scheme-possibly-port-from-servlet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The protocol is HTTP/1.1, since it is a specific version of HTTP. The scheme as given by [`ServletRequest#getScheme`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getScheme%28%29)itself is `http`:

```
new URL(httpRequest.getScheme(),
httpRequest.getServerName(),
httpRequest.getServerPort(),
httpRequest.getContextPath().concat("/foo/bar.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 I'll suggest you use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` and it's static methods, such as `ServletUriComponentsBuilder#fromCurrentRequest` which helps you build your URL using the previous Request.

Example:

```java
URL url = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
     .fromCurrentRequest()
     .path("/foo/bar.html")
     .encode() // To encode your url... always usefull
     .build()
     .toUri()
     .toURL()
```

Whatsmore, if you wanna redirect on the same app, please just return "redirect:/foo/bar.html" with status 302 and spring boot MVC will transform it into a normal redirection.

Example:

```java
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/some/endpoint")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
public ModelAndView redirectToFoo() {
   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/foo/bar.html");
}
```