# Check https urls on a JUnit Selenium test case

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, https, assert

I need to check that certain pages from a site, are https, like the login and personal info ones, so I think that an assert of the url with a ".contains" to check the existance of "https" in the url, but wanted to know if there's a better way to do this.

something like:

```
Public class mySite {

     WebDriver driver ;
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";

     driver.get(baseUrl);
     assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://"));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would use `startsWith` instead of `contains`, but this about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: String representation of just the host, scheme, possibly port from servlet request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104611/java-string-representation-of-just-the-host-scheme-possibly-port-from-servlet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more sensible one would be to use `startsWith(String prefix)` as it checks if the String starts with the prefix specified (in your case `http`). Since `http` occurs at the start of every URL, I suggest going with this.