# Is there a Java method that encodes a collection of parameters as a URL query component?

Tags: java, http, url, encoding

Is there a widely-used Java library that does something like what [dojo.objectToQuery()](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.objectToQuery) does? E.g. (assuming the use of HttpCore's [HttpParams](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/index.html) object, but any key-value mapping will do):

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams()
    .setParameter("foo", "bar")
    .setParameter("thud", "grunt");
UnknownLibrary.toQueryString(params);
```

should yield "foo=bar&thud=grunt".

I know it's not hard to write but it seems like it should have already been written. I just can't find it.

Comment: It turns out that HttpParams was not anything like I had thought when I wrote this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up writing my own. It can be called like

```
URIUtils.withQuery(uri, "param1", "value1", "param2", "value2");
```

which isn't so bad.

```
/**
 * Concatenates <code>uri</code> with a query string generated from
 * <code>params</code>.
 *
 * @param uri the base URI
 * @param params a <code>Map</code> of key/value pairs
 * @return a new <code>URI</code>
 */

public static URI withQuery(URI uri, Map<String, String> params) {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    char separator = '?';
    for (Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
        query.append(separator);
        separator = '&';
        try {
            query.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(param.getValue())) {
                query.append('=');
                query.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return URI.create(uri.toString() + query.toString());
}

/**
 * Concatenates <code>uri</code> with a query string generated from
 * <code>params</code>.  The members of <code>params</code> will be
 * interpreted as {key1, val1, key2, val2}.  Empty values can be given
 * as <code>""</code> or <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @param uri the base URI
 * @param params the key/value pairs in sequence
 * @return a new <code>URI</code>
 */
public static URI withQuery(URI uri, String... params) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i += 2) {
        String key = params[i];
        String val = i + 1 < params.length ? params[i + 1] : "";
        map.put(key, val);
    }
    return withQuery(uri, map);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Why reinvent the wheel? [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) has URLEncodedUtils:

```
   List<BasicNameValuePair> params = Arrays.asList(new BasicNameValuePair("\\%^ &=@#:", "\\%^ &=@#:"));
   String query = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need a library for that. I didn't find one in HttpCore either so I wrote something like this,

```
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(baseUrl);

    char separator;

    if (baseUrl.indexOf('?') > 0)
        separator = '&';
    else
        separator = '?';

    for (Parameter p : parameters) {
        sb.append(separator);
        try {
            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(p.name, "UTF-8"));
            if (p.value != null) {
                sb.append('=');
                sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(p.value, "UTF-8"));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // Not really possible, throw unchecked exception
            throw new IllegalStateException("No UTF-8");
        }

        separator = '&';
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have JAX-RS there is javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder; other than that you should primarily be aware of URLEncoder and URLDecoder which will at least encode the pieces of the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries that can help you with URI building (don't reinvent the wheel). Here is one to get you started:

---

#### [org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.5.RELEASE](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-web%7C4.2.5.RELEASE%7Cjar)

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
...
return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).queryParam(key, value).build().toUri();
```

---

**See also:** [GIST > URI Builder Tests](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/b4f35bf5e5e5a444aff20c4616b51513)

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383916) - [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383816) - [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383802) - [4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383788). Instead, flag the question as a duplicate if you believe it to be so.