# Is there a Java package to handle building URLs?

Tags: java, url

What I'm looking for specifically is some code in Java that will take a `Map` object and convert it into a query string that I can append to a URL I return.  I'm sure there's a library that does this and much more, but I can't find it with a quick Google search.  Anyone know of one that will do this?

Comment: I had the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405731/is-there-a-java-method-that-encodes-a-collection-of-parameters-as-a-url-query-com . No good answer though. :-/

Comment: See also http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/construct-build-uri/ and https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-open-source-URL-manipulation-library-in-Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the idiomatic way to compose a URL or URI in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-compose-a-url-or-uri-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found [apache httpcomponents](https://hc.apache.org/) to be a solid and versatile library for dealing with HTTP in Java. However, here's a sample class, which might suffice for building URL query strings:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class QueryString {

    private String query = "";

    public QueryString(HashMap<String, String> map) {
        Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            query += URLEncoder.encode(pairs.getKey(), "utf-8") + "=" +
            URLEncoder.encode(pairs.getValue(), "utf-8");
            if (it.hasNext()) { query += "&"; }
        }
    }

    public QueryString(Object name, Object value) {
        query = URLEncoder.encode(name.toString(), "utf-8") + "=" +
            URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "utf-8");
    }

    public QueryString() { query = ""; }

    public synchronized void add(Object name, Object value) {
        if (!query.trim().equals("")) query += "&";
        query += URLEncoder.encode(name.toString(), "utf-8") + "=" +
            URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "utf-8");
    }

    public String toString() { return query; }
}
```

Usage:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("hello", "world");
map.put("lang", "en");

QueryString q = new QueryString(map);
System.out.println(q);
// => "hello=world&lang=en"
```

Comment: Looks good!  However, I strongly recommend that you use generics in your code!

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but yah the <code>URLEncoder.encode(String s)</code> method is deprecated in favor of one that takes a format argument as well. Other than that, this is great, thanks.

Comment: @miku is there a class in HttpComponents that does what your code does?

Answer (score 6):

Try [URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) from [Apache Http Compoments](http://hc.apache.org/) (HttpClient 4).

It does not actually take a map, but is well suited for building URIs.

Answer (score 1):

There's [this](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/17679/0/page/3) online, so you can simply call any of:

```
InputStream serverInput = post(URL url, Map parameters); 
InputStream serverInput = post(URL url, Map parameters); 
InputStream serverInput = post(URL url, Map cookies, Map parameters); 
InputStream serverInput = post(URL url, String[] cookies, Object[] parameters); 
InputStream serverInput = post(URL url, Object[] parameters).
```

He provides the source code too.