# Create URL from a String

Tags: java, http, url

It is a very basic question. But i am unable to find an answer in Java documentation and unable to test it as well since i don't know if such method exist or not.

I might receive a URL String which could be

`http://www.example1.com`

or

`http://www.example1.com/`

and then i will get resource path which might start with `/api/v1/status.xml` or it would be like `api/v1/status.xml`

I was looking at `URL` class and I can handle the first part i.e. fetching the hostURL to make it an HTTPS or HTTP request. The problem is appending the resource path. either i have to check it manually if the first letter is `/` or not. I was wondering if this functionality is already in some class or not.

Comment: Is this similar to what you're looking for? It might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861620/is-there-a-java-package-to-handle-building-urls

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL(yourUrl, "/api/v1/status.xml");
```

According to the javadocs this constructor just appends whatever resource to the end of your domain, so you would want to create 2 urls:

```
URL domain = new URL("http://example.com");
URL url = new URL(domain + "/files/resource.xml");
```

Sources: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: What if `URL url = new URL(domain + "files/resource.xml");` ? MalformedURL ? ... what if `domain=www.example.com/` and `new URL (domain + "/files/resources.xml");` ... again malformed

Comment: I've seen many times where an application first checks the URL string for `if (domain.endsWith("/")) {domain = domain.substring(0, domain.length()-1);}` For all other problems, catch MalformedURLException and handle from there.

Comment: I'm getting MalformedURLException just because the protocol is not "http". OMG /facepalm

Comment: using java.net.URI is the better way