# Unable to insert documents into mongodb database gives NetworkOnMainthread EXception

Tags: java, android, mongodb

Im making an android app to fetch data from user and store it in a mongodb database

mongodb runs on localhost:27017 and im able to connect to it using 10.0.3.2:27017 on genymotion emulator

here is LoginActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static DB db;
    static DBCollection locations;

    public String name,middlename,surname,userid,profilelink,imageUrl,emailid,gender,birthday;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                nextActivity(newProfile);
            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();


        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                nextActivity(profile);



                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("JSON",response.toString());

                                try {
                                    emailid=object.getString("email");
                                    gender=object.getString("gender");
                                    birthday=object.getString("birthday");

                                    TextView nameView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailr);
                                    nameView6.setText(emailid);
                                    TextView nameView7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.genderr);
                                    nameView7.setText(gender);
                                    TextView nameView8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birthdayr);
                                    nameView8.setText(birthday);

                                    String[] dset={emailid,gender,birthday};
                                    yalla(dset);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "email,gender,birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            }
        };
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Facebook login
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        nextActivity(profile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

    }

    private void nextActivity(Profile profile){
        if(profile != null){
            Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
            main.putExtra("middlename", profile.getMiddleName());
            main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
            main.putExtra("userid", profile.getId());
            main.putExtra("profilelink", profile.getLinkUri());
            main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString());
            startActivity(main);
        }
    }

    public static void yalla(String[] args){
        String[] dset;
        dset=args;

        //try {
        String uri = "mongodb://10.0.3.2:27017";
        Log.v("enterhere", dset[0]);
        MongoClientURI mongoClientURI=new MongoClientURI(uri);
        //MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.0.3.2:27017/test");
        Log.v("connectedserver", dset[0]);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("users");
        Log.v("Connect to database successfully",database.getName());
        MongoCollection mongoCollection = database.getCollection("assest");
        Log.v("collection", dset[0]);

            Document doc = new Document("emailid", dset[0])
                    .append("gender", dset[1])
                    .append("birthday", dset[2]);
            Log.v("document update", dset[0]);
            mongoCollection.insertOne(doc);
            Log.v("doc insertion", dset[0]);
            mongoClient.close();
        //} catch (MongoException e)
        //{
        //    e.getStackTrace();
        //}
         }
}
```

Error on android studio

```
V/document update: zissujith@gmail.com
I/cluster: No server chosen by PrimaryServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=10.0.3.2:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
I/connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:17}] to 10.0.3.2:27017
I/cluster: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=10.0.3.2:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 14]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=9233253}
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 413K, 5% free 12382K/12935K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 17ms
I/connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to 10.0.3.2:27017 because the underlying connection was closed.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62fe288)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  com.mongodb.MongoException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:125)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:46)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:366)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:94)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:80)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:69)
                      at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86)
                      at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:184)
                      at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:177)
                      at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:141)
                      at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:747)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:730)
                      at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:482)
                      at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:277)
                      at com.sujithsizon.lzlogin3.LoginActivity.yalla(LoginActivity.java:224)
                      at com.sujithsizon.lzlogin3.LoginActivity$3$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java:99)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1368)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
                      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
                      at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
                      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
                      at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:46) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:366) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:94) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:80) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:69) 
                      at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86) 
                      at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:184) 
                      at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:177) 
                      at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:141) 
                      at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:72) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:747) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:730) 
                      at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:482) 
                      at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:277) 
                      at com.sujithsizon.lzlogin3.LoginActivity.yalla(LoginActivity.java:224) 
                      at com.sujithsizon.lzlogin3.LoginActivity$3$1.onCompleted(LoginActivity.java:99) 
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:304) 
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1368) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Async Task for this. I don't know much about mongoDB, but assuming your `yalla` method has heavy network operation which includes mongoDB.

Try to add `yalla` method into new AyancTask.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

      //Include your mongoDB accessing method here, in background thread.

 }
 }
```

And you can execute this method by the following line from your activity.

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Now you are including your method in AsyncTask, and passing `URL` as arguments, Just provide the links via `execute()` method. No need to use this `String[] = args`, which currently you are using in your methos.

For more details on AsyncTask, refer the official docs from [this link :)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: thanks, btw how will i cast string into a url, i tried new URL (String), but it is returning null

Comment: Refer this answer for your doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730685/create- url-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

I am actually trying to do the same and found mongoclient won't work so I used the common class to connect to my server on mlab then I used an asynkTask inner class with HTTPUrlConnection to get the data I stored, check out this link for querying urls for mlab-> http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/
Also check this out-> https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RSZ2pyhfR0I

```
 public class Common {
private static String DB_NAME = "edmtdev";
private static String COLLECTION_NAME =        "user";
public static String API_KEY = "YOUR API   KEY";

public static String getAddressSingle(User user)    {
String baseUrl =       String.format("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/%s/collections/%s", DB_NAME,  COLLECTION_NAME);
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new   StringBuilder(baseUrl);
    stringBuilder.append("/"+user.get_id().getOid()+"?apiKey="+API_KEY);
return stringBuilder.toString():
}
```