# how to send both string and array type parameter on server in android

Tags: android, arrays

I want to send data like `packageid[]=1&packageid[]2`. The same applies for the amount. The key will be the same, but the value will be different.My Packageid[] would be same and values would be different.and my question is different.

```
HashMap<String,String> params1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
params1.put("customerId", String.valueOf(helpervalue));
params1.put("vechileId", String.valueOf(vehicalId));
params1.put("timeslotId", String.valueOf(timeSlotId));
params1.put("registrationYear", String.valueOf(registeryear));
params1.put("franchiseId", String.valueOf(helpervalue2));
params1.put("jobDate", String.valueOf(date));
params1.put("vehicleRegistrationNumber", String.valueOf(register));
params1.put("totalAmount", String.valueOf(total)+"&"+getURlFromArray1(strint));`

private String getURlFromArray1(int arr[]) {
    String makeupSTR = "";

    for(int val : arr)
        makeupSTR += arr1Key+"="+val+"&";
    if(makeupSTR.contains("&"))
         makeupSTR = makeupSTR.substring(0, makeupSTR.lastIndexOf("&"));
    return makeupSTR;
}
```

I am expecting to send the following query string structure:

```
?access=true&action=place_order&type=Add&franchiseId=1&jobDate=2016-01-30&customerId=1&vehicleRegistrationNumber=1&vehicleMakeId=1&registrationYear=2016&totalAmount=250.36&packageIds[]=1&packageIds[]=2&packageAmounts[]=20&packageAmounts[]=30
```

which responds with JSON like

```
{
    status: false,
    displayMessage: "This Slot has just been booked. Please Select a different Time Slot."
}
```

Comment: this is actual data which i have to send on server ..

Comment: http://client.zoneonedigital.com/carwash_v2/api/ws/controller/?access=true&action=place_order&type=Add&franchiseId=1&jobDate=2016-01-30&customerId=1&vehicleRegistrationNumber=1&vehicleMakeId=1&registrationYear=2016&totalAmount=250.36&packageIds[]=1&packageIds[]=2&packageAmounts[]=20&packageAmounts[]=30

Comment: It's so confusing to read code with for and if statements written that way. Ive added your linked json to the question, I can't see an array there?

Comment: very sorry for rewriting...i have to send exactly this data..&franchiseId=1&jobDate=2016-01-31&customerId=12&vehicleRegistrationNumber=‌​1&vehicleMakeId=1&registrationYear=2016&totalAmount=250.36&packageIds[]=1&package‌​Ids[]=2&packageAmounts[]=20&packageAmounts[]=30

Comment: Please don't use the comments for code like text or additional information. If you must clarify something, find the edit link under your question to add anything to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert map to url query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809877/how-to-convert-map-to-url-query-string)

Comment: Another duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861620/is-there-a-java-package-to-handle-building-urls

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how to send this "array". You can simply send it as a `;`-separated string: `key=val1;val2;val3`, for example. In server, you split them using `;`.

Example:

```
String values[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
String all = "";
for (String v : values)
   all += v + ";";
all = all.substring(0, all.length() - 1);
String param = "key=" + all;
```

You can better send json/xml.

Comment: packageid[]=1&packageid[]=2&packageid[]=3&&packageid[]=4

Comment: very sorry for rewriting...i have to send exactly this data..&franchiseId=1&jobDate=2016-01-31&customerId=12&vehicleRegistrationNumber=1&vehicleMakeId=1&registrationYear=2016&totalAmount=250.36&packageIds[]=1&packageIds[]=2&packageAmounts[]=20&packageAmounts[]=30

Comment: bro my values are coming ...in a string from previous activity..and now i have convert it into int array...how can i put it as ..key=val1;val2;val3

Comment: like this `packageIds=1;2;20;30&registrationYear=2016& ...`

Comment: i am not talking about ..how to put static values....i have a String Array which have all packageid...that is strint[i]....

Comment: Bro see my method private String getURlFromArray1(int arr[])

Comment: And exact requirement is...String orderurl="http://client.zoneonedigital.com/carwash_v2/api/ws/controller/?access=true&action=place_order&type=Add&totalAmount=250.36&packageIds[]=1&packageIds[]=2&packageAmounts[]=20&packageAmounts[]=30"....please see my code also...