# Building URI to consume REST services

Tags: java, rest, uri, jax-rs, resteasy

I need to develop & consume lot of REST services. Instead of hard coding the URI at server & client, I want it to be a generic approach. So in future if the URI changes, I can change it at one place.

Is there any best way to build URI? Here are some sample REST service I want to write,

```
http://server/services/user/authenticate?user=x&pass=y
http://server/services/user/authorize?user=x
http://server/services/session/create/id
http://server/services/session/close/id
http://server/services/shopping/orders
http://server/services/shopping/orders/id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good url builder for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/is-there-a-good-url-builder-for-java)

Comment: No. I need a suggestion on Server side also. When creating REST service, the Path has to be mentioned.

Comment: So you basically need some way in which even the URL value for the REST methods can be easily configurable?

Comment: Yes. a common approach to use both server & client side.

Comment: That is called HATEOAS.The HATEOAS can be used for child services. Here I will have predefined base services, that I want to create & consume.

Comment: Are you using Spring at your application?

Comment: Will both the client and server be written using java?

Comment: Yes. I am using Spring & RESTEasy. It will be in Java only.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create a BootStrap service that gives you the current URLs?