# How to build url in java?

Tags: java, string, http, url

I am building a String with StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("my parameters");
builder.append("other parameters");
```

Then i build a Url

```
Url url = new Url(builder.toString());
```

And then i try the connection

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But the url seems not to be right from the results i get. It's like some parameter is being false passed. That's why i think the problem is in the part of the StringBuilder.

The problem is in a double parameter i try to pass.

```
double longitude = 23.433114;
String lng = String.ValueOf(longitude);
```

And then i put it in the url.
But if i give it as a string the result is correct.

```
String lng = "23.433114"
```

Is UrlEncoding necessary? I will try what is suggested below.

Comment: You should be using a library which does URI Templates (see [here](https://github.com/fge/uri-template) for example)

Comment: @RealSkeptic `URLEncoder.encode()` encodes for application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is quite different from encoding query parameters/URI fragments/etc

Comment: @fge No, URLencode is a standard encoding scheme. It is used both for parameters in GET queries and for parameters in POST queries which are application/x-www-form-urlencoded. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: @fge It is exactly the same thing for parameter values. He didn't say anything about URI fragments. Parameter names should also be `URLEncoded.`

Comment: @RealSkeptic @EJP sorry but that's wrong. In query parameters, for instance, a space becomes `%20`; as I said, the method you mention encodes for forms in which the space becomes `+`. And that is only one example

Comment: @fge No, [a space becomes + in query parameters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#form-content-type), and that's what `URLEncoder` does. Despite its name it has nothing to do with URLs specifically.

Comment: @fge - try both of them in a query. You'll be surprised. + Is an acceptable replacement for space in GET queries. But if you don't believe Wikipedia, Try [The HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3)

Comment: fge is correct. The first two sentences of the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) couldn't be clearer: “Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static methods for converting a String to the application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format.” Using URLEncoder for query parameters in a URL is wrong. I know it looks similar but it's not correct. The correct way to encode a query is with any java.net.URI constructor that takes more than one argument.

Comment: @VGR The requirement is the same whether it's a query parameter or a form parameter.

Comment: @EJP forms.html in the W3C spec describes how to encode data submitted from an HTML form.  However, data submitted for any other purpose (such as a REST service) should use URI encoding.

Comment: @EJP why do you quote the HTML spec when we are talking about URIs?

Comment: @RealSkeptic why do you quote the HTML spec when we are talking about URIs?

Comment: @fge Because we're talking about the way one builds a query string. The HTML spec describes exactly that, and tells you that it's done in the same way and using the same standard for both GET and PUT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the idiomatic way to compose a URL or URI in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-compose-a-url-or-uri-in-java)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try apache's `URIBuilder` : [[Documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html)]

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;

// ...

URIBuilder b = new URIBuilder("http://example.com");
b.addParameter("t", "search");
b.addParameter("q", "apples");

Url url = b.build().toUrl();
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly. The only problem is that it throws checked exceptions which are boring to handle.

Comment: They are boring to be captured like any other exceptions.. nope? :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to create the URL and consume it through a GET request, it would be better to use a library that helps you in this process. You can use [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) or another library like [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) that is built on top of HttpComponents which ease all this work.

Here's an example using Unirest:

```
HttpResponse<String> stringResponse = Unirest.get("https://www.youtube.com/results")
    .field("search_query", "eñe")
    .asString();
System.out.println(stringResponse.getBody());
```

This will retrieve the HTML response corresponding to all the results from a search on youtube using `"eñe"`. The `ñ` character will be encoded for you.

DISCLAIMER: I'm not attached to Unirest in any mean. I'm not a developer or a sponsor of this project. I'm only a happy user of this framework.

Comment: Hey, Its qute late but can we pass value .field("search_query", "eñe") in get request??

Answer (score 1):

And another option, this time using Spring framework (especially useful when doing some automated tests)

```java
UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
                .scheme(URIScheme.HTTP.getId())
                .host("host")
                .port(8000)
                .path("/employee")
                .pathSegment("{employeeName}", "{anotherThing}")
                // this build(xxx) will automatically perform encoding
                .build("John", "YetMoreData")
                .toURL();
```

Comment: The lillte problem with this tool is that not all special characters are encoded. For instance plus signs in query params are not encoded!

Comment: Hum, didn't know that. Maybe this method does what you spoke about? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#encode()