# Build URL in java

Tags: java, url, build

Trying to build `http://IP:4567/foldername/1234?abc=xyz`. I don't know much about it but I wrote below code from searching from google:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyUrlConstruct {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        try {
            String protocol = "http";
            String host = "IP";
            int port = 4567;
            String path = "foldername/1234";
            URL url = new URL (protocol, host, port, path);
            System.out.println(url.toString()+"?");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to build URL `http://IP:port/foldername/1234?`. I am stuck at query part. Please help me to move forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java)

Comment: @px06 urls need escaping and validation, concat is not going to cut it because if `abc=xyz` contains some other `=, ? or &` it will be broken.
Use a dedicated lib for this, for extremely simple cases concat may work though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build url in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641809/how-to-build-url-in-java)

Comment: As of Java 7 there is the (EE) builtin `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder` which does this for you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In general non-Java terms, a URL is a specialized type of URI.  You can use the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class (which is more modern than the venerable URL class, which has been around since Java 1.0) to create a URI more reliably, and you can convert it to a URL with the [toURL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#toURL--) method of URI:

```
String protocol = "http";
String host = "example.com";
int port = 4567;
String path = "/foldername/1234";
String auth = null;
String fragment = null;
URI uri = new URI(protocol, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```

Note that the `path` needs to start with a slash.

Comment: If i have to user fragment in this code with "&" how can i use it ? e.g "http://IP:4567/foldername/1234?abc=xyz&def=stu"

Comment: That is not a fragment.  That's just multiple query parameters.  Unfortunately, URI currently has no easy to assemble those;  you’ll have to build the query string yourself.  Note that query parameter values usually need to be [encoded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: As others stated this is OK for simple cases, but if you also need to escape params this will be problematic (&, ?, =, ...)

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy This is [an open bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6306820) which for some reason Oracle doesn’t seem to feel is worth bothering to address.

Comment: @VGR probably for backward compatibility ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Backward compatibility is of paramount importance, but adding new constructors and methods would not break anything for existing code.  Adding a template-less version of the [UriBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) class from Java EE would be even better.

Answer (score 80):

You can just pass raw spec

```
new URL("http://IP:4567/foldername/1234?abc=xyz");
```

Or you can take something like [`org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/latest/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) and build it in safe manner with proper url encoding

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http");
builder.setHost("IP");
builder.setPath("/foldername/1234");
builder.addParameter("abc", "xyz");
URL url = builder.build().toURL();
```

Comment: Already had this lib as a dependency thanks to Apache http client lib, really helpful and simple.

Comment: Note that this builder can also be used for partial url building, for example just for the parameters: `... builder.addParameter(...); ... builder.toString()` will return just this part even if other parts are missing.

Answer (score 38):

## Use OkHttp

There is a very popular library named [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) which has been starred **45K** times on GitHub. With this library, you can build the url like below:

```
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;

URL url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .host("example.com")
    .port(4567)
    .addPathSegments("foldername/1234")
    .addQueryParameter("abc", "xyz")
    .build().url();
```

Or you can simply parse an URL:

```
URL url = HttpUrl.parse("http://example.com:4567/foldername/1234?abc=xyz").url();
```

Comment: I would avoid using a full HTTP client if all you need is to build a URL string. That's a heavy dependency for a light task.

Comment: @NeuroXc yes what you said makes sense. I come from Node.js world where it's the dependency hell, so I get used to managing dependencies. On the other hand, it's not that bad since a heavy dependency won't make your app slow. It will make your app bigger though.So it depends. It could be an issue but in some case people don't care it.

Comment: I used your solution while migrating from an older Http client to okhttp, had to manually build the Url at onc place in the code base. thanks for this! Also we can use `HttpUrl url ` instead of `URL url`

Answer (score 14):

### Using Spring Framework:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
  .scheme(scheme)
  .host(host)
  .path(path)
  .build()
  .toUri()
  .toURL();
```

> A new `UriComponentsBuilder` class helps to create `UriComponents`
> instances by providing fine-grained control over all aspects of
> preparing a URI including construction, expansion from template
> variables, and encoding.

► [Read more ...](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder)

► [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

Answer (score 13):

If you happen to be using Spring already, I have found the `org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder` to be quite nifty. Here is how you would use it in your case.

```
final URL myUrl = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl("http://IP:4567/foldername/1234?abc=xyz")
        .build()
        .toUri()
        .toURL();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android, you can use the `Uri.Builder` API. Example:

```
val uri = Uri.Builder().scheme("https").authority("s3.amazonaws.com").appendEncodedPath(bucketName).appendEncodedPath(fileName).build()
```

Docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder