# How to generate azure blob storage SAS url using java?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I want to generate a SAS url that i can share with user to connect to storage account and upload a file to any location.

How can i generate the SAS url using java api.

i found one documentation but looks like all api are depreciated https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-blob/12.0.0/com/azure/storage/blob/sas/BlobServiceSasSignatureValues.html

---

```
Env:
Java Version: 8.0
BLOB STORAGE JAVA SDK: group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.8.0'
```

Comment: @Frank Gong not really helped..
i can't even see there is example documentation available for java https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=dotnet#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob-container

Comment: Please check if this helps https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java

Comment: @MohitSingh, This is the document I [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#java), but I found some problems, so I deleted it.

Comment: @Frank Gong currently we don't have any documentation for java api?

the post you shared still had problem?

Comment: @MohitSingh. Please wait for me to test.

Comment: @Frank Gong.  Sure..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
BlobContainerSasPermission blobContainerSasPermission = new BlobContainerSasPermission()
                .setReadPermission(true)
                .setWritePermission(true)
                .setListPermission(true);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues builder = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1), blobContainerSasPermission)
                .setProtocol(SasProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY);
        BlobClient client = new BlobClientBuilder()
                .connectionString("connection string")
                .blobName("")
                .buildClient();
        String blobContainerName = "test";
        return String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s?%s",client.getAccountName(), blobContainerName, client.generateSas(builder));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a REST API that you can call. See at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas.

Comment: do we have java api for building this url?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498767/build-url-in-java#39498881

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure storage SDK for maven as follows:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>8.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then follow the below code to generate SAS token which you can append to your storage URL.

```
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(blobConnectionString);
        
     // Create a blob service client
     CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
                              
     CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
    
     Date expirationTime = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(7).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy sharedAccessPolicy=new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
    sharedAccessPolicy.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, 
        SharedAccessBlobPermissions.WRITE,SharedAccessBlobPermissions.ADD));
    sharedAccessPolicy.setSharedAccessStartTime(new Date());
    sharedAccessPolicy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(expirationTime);
        
    String sasToken = container.generateSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessPolicy, null);
```

Comment: That dependency is wrong. It's `com.azure` not `com.microsoft.azure`.